# OAuth 2.0 Server to server Credentials authorization Fail(Search Console - Webmaster tools)

Tags: python, google-search-console, google-api-python-client, google-api-webmasters

I'm trying to use OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server application for google webmaster tools(Search Console) so I've followed the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#overview).

This Application is NOT on `Google App Engine` or `Google Compute Engine`

Created a *service account* and enabled *domain-wide delegation*. Downloaded the `.json` file and stored it to the root of the script.

Sample:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http    

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        'keyfile.json', scopes=scopes)

http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())

webmasters_service = build('webmasters', 'v3', http=http_auth)

site_list = webmasters_service.sites().list().execute()
print(site_list)
```

But I'm getting

`{}` Empty dataset. Even if I change the email address in the `keyfile.json`. This tells me that the file is not getting used somehow. So the attempt the get the lists of the sites in the account resulting as Empty.

If I do

```
site_list = webmasters_service.sitemaps().list(siteUrl="www.example.com").execute()
```

I get:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/www.example.com/sitemaps?alt=json returned "User does not have sufficient permission for site 'http://www.example.com/'. See also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999.">
```

Which again tells me that, this account has no right to get the sitemaps of the given `URL` because it doesn't has the appropriate permissions.

This Account is the owner account and the `service account` has owner permissions.

Any Ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question but here is how I made it to work;

- Go to: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en
- Select your site
- Click the gear(top right) and click on `Users and Property Owners`
- Now go to: https://console.developers.google.com/permissions/projectpermissions?project=PROJECT-NAME
- Copy the e-mail address for the service account and add it `Users and Property Owners` with **FULL** Permission level

So bottom line is, on the

- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority

and

- https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/quickstart/quickstart-python#step_1_enable_the_search_console_api

... tutorials someone forgot to mention about adding the newly generated e-mail address to the app's permission's section...

Comment: which version of `oauth2client` are you using? I tried to `from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials` but it doesn't look like `ServiceAccountCredentials` is included in my version of `oauth2client.service_account`.  I see a `ServiceAccountCredentials` class...

Comment: Im using `google-api-python-client (1.5.0)`. That's version came with `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`. Hope it helps. [Doc](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/quickstart/quickstart-python#step_1_enable_the_search_console_api)

Comment: I originally ran `pip install --upgrade oauth2client` but since I had an old version of `pip` it wouldn't upgrade properly.  I'm up-to-date with `pip` and now `oauth2client` has the `ServiceAccountCredentials` class.  Thanks!

Comment: My email has multiple SearchConsole sites associated with it.  Instead of placing this new email (in the `keyfile.json`) I delegated my email credentials using `delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated('user@example.org')` and then `http_auth = delegated_credentials.authorize(Http())`, which gave me access to all of the sites my email address has access to.

Comment: ohh I was looking for a way to do that. Thank you for the tip